# Looking for Blender source code of version 2.79.7

Tags: development, source-code

Where can I find the source code, corresponding to this exact build 2.79.7 blender-2.79 e045fe53f1b0 ? - https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/latest/

Comment: I haven't tried but I assume `git checkout e045fe53f1b0` would do it. Have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The source code of blender is available in a git repository, as documented in the [blender wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender), which explains how to build the code for your operating system:

> git.blender.org/blender.git

There is also a mirror of the code repository on github: https://github.com/blender/blender

The version tags may be used to navigate through history and pull the desired version.

Comment: Did you just messed up your hyper link in your answer? Only the last one link to the correct place

Comment: Indeed, thanks for letting me know. I just fixed them. The second one is a git repository, not meant to be navigated via a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both!
Indeed using git to to get the code:

git clone git://git.blender.org/blender.git

and then (after entering the repository directory - "cd blender"):

git checkout e045fe53f1b0

to get that particular commit, worked.
(I didn't know git enough to think of that solution.)

Answer (score 0):

all git commits are logged under some id(commit hash).
`git checkout "commmitHash"` This statement resets the head to the particular commit.
Try this,
I found this commit at [commit link](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/commit/9e707802c23318898e140da71a4c0a04e1c7125a)

commit hash => `9e707802c23318898e140da71a4c0a04e1c7125a`